# Android Event Handling - Multiple Buttons

Tags: android, event-handling

Can we create a centralized event handler for multiple buttons in Android?
If so, how can we do that?

Comment: Did you mean firing same event for two or more buttons?

Comment: Please read this before asking a question. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I mean to create an event handler like if I press Volume up and Volume Down at the same time I must trigger an event or call a click handler.

Answer (score 3):

Yonatan Nir's solution is the easiest but if you're already using [Butterknife](http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/) you can do it like this:

```
@OnClick({ R.id.button1, R.id.button2, R.id.button3})
public void onButtonClicked(View theViewThatIsClicked) {
  Toast.makeText(this, "Clicked!", LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it by using the `View` parameter you are given:

```
@Override
public void onClick(final View v)
{
 switch (v.getId()) 
 {
    case R.id.Button1: ....
    case R.id.Button2: ...
 }
}
```

For example:

```
class MyActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener
{


@Override
public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    Button button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Button1);
    Button button2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Button2);

    button1 .setOnClickListener(this);
    button2 .setOnClickListener(this);
}

 @Override
public void onClick(final View v)
{
 switch (v.getId()) 
 {
    case R.id.Button1: ....
    case R.id.Button2: ...
 }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a pseudo code for this:

```
      class FooActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener{


        //inside onCreate(), find buttons with their ids, For ex;
        Button btn1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn1);
        Buttn btn2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn2)

        // and  register listeners for appropriate Buttons
        btn1.setOnClickListener(this);
        btn2.setOnClickListener(this)

        //then implement the listener interface method 
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
           int id = v.getId();
           if(id == R.id.btn1 || id==R.id.btn2){
              doSameForBothButtons();
            }

          }
        }
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I centralize my Click handlers.

Note: It's useful for different types of Views as well, not only Buttons.
**Even mixed** types (i.e.: you can handle an ImageButton, a TextView and a Button using the same method for all).

Example layout (note the `android:onClick="clickHandler"` attribute on each Button):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#f000"
    >
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:text="1"
        android:onClick="clickHandler"
    />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:text="2"
        android:onClick="clickHandler"
    />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:text="3"
        android:onClick="clickHandler"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

Accompanying code (note the `clickHandler` method):

```
package com.dergolem.abc_2;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class MultiClick
extends Activity
{

    Button btn1 = null;
    Button btn2 = null;
    Button btn3 = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

        setContentView(R.layout.multi_click);

        btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button1);
        btn2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button2);
        btn3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button3);
    }

    public void clickHandler(final View v)
    {
        String str = "";
        switch (v.getId())
        {
            case R.id.Button1:
            {
                str = "1";
                break;
            }
            case R.id.Button2:
            {
                str = "2";
                break;
            }
            case R.id.Button3:
            {
                str = "3";
                break;
            }
        }
        Toast.makeText(this, "Button " + str, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```